# this.bottomSheet.open is not a function when i try open a BottomSheet with Angular Material in ionic

Tags: angular-material, ionic4, bottom-sheet

I have the following code based on the angular material documentation:

In my HTML

```
 <button mat-raised-button (click)="openBottomSheet()">Abrir BottomSheet</button>
```

and, in my page ts archive :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {MatBottomSheet, MatBottomSheetRef} from '@angular/material/bottom-sheet';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.page.scss'],
})
export class LoginPage implements OnInit {

  constructor(private bottomSheet: MatBottomSheet) {}

  openBottomSheet ()
  {
    this.bottomSheet.open(BottomSheetOverviewExampleSheet)
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'bottom-sheet-overview-example-sheet',
  templateUrl: 'bottom-sheet-overview-example-sheet.html',
})
export class BottomSheetOverviewExampleSheet {
  constructor(private bottomSheetRef: MatBottomSheetRef<BottomSheetOverviewExampleSheet>) {}

  openLink(event: MouseEvent): void {
    this.bottomSheetRef.dismiss();
    event.preventDefault();
  }

}
```

The problem is that when trying to show the bottomsheet I get the following error:

**ERROR TypeError: this.bottomSheet.open is not a function
    at LoginPage.openBottomSheet**

In my page component i have :

```
import { LoginPageRoutingModule } from './login-routing.module';
import { LoginPage } from './login.page';
import { MaterialModule } from '../material.module';
import {MatBottomSheetModule} from '@angular/material/bottom-sheet'



@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    LoginPageRoutingModule,
    MaterialModule,
    MatBottomSheetModule

  ],
  declarations: [LoginPage]
})
export class LoginPageModule {}
```

**The material Module**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import {
  MatTableModule,
  MatStepperModule,
  MatButtonModule,
  MatFormFieldModule,
  MatInputModule,
  MatOptionModule,
  MatSelectModule,
  MatIconModule,
  MatPaginatorModule,
  MatSortModule
} from "@angular/material";
import { MatCheckboxModule } from '@angular/material/checkbox';
import {MatBottomSheetRef, MatBottomSheet} from '@angular/material/bottom-sheet';




@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  providers: [
    { provide: MatBottomSheetRef, useValue: {} },
    { provide: MatBottomSheet, useValue: {} },
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
  ],
  exports: [
    MatTableModule,
    MatStepperModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatOptionModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatCheckboxModule
  ]
})
export class MaterialModule { }
```

Answer (score 1):

You must import the material design module that holds this function.

Make sure you have `import {MatBottomSheetModule} from '@angular/material/bottom-sheet';`
imported in your component module or app module.

**Update:**

Instead of

```
import {
  MatTableModule,
  MatStepperModule,
  MatButtonModule,
  MatFormFieldModule,
  MatInputModule,
  MatOptionModule,
  MatSelectModule,
  MatIconModule,
  MatPaginatorModule,
  MatSortModule
} from "@angular/material";
```

try this,

```
import {MatBottomSheetRef, MatBottomSheet, MatBottomSheetModule} from '@angular/material/bottom-sheet';
import {MatCheckboxModule} from "@angular/material/checkbox";
import {MatFormFieldModule} from "@angular/material/form-field";
import {MatOptionModule} from "@angular/material/core";
import {MatSortModule} from "@angular/material/sort";
import {MatTableModule} from "@angular/material/table";
import {MatSelectModule} from "@angular/material/select";
import {MatIconModule} from "@angular/material/icon";
import {MatPaginatorModule} from "@angular/material/paginator";
import {MatStepperModule} from "@angular/material/stepper";
import {MatInputModule} from "@angular/material/input";
import {MatButtonModule} from "@angular/material/button";
```

in `MaterialModule`

Comment: Check out their stackblitz, https://stackblitz.com/angular/gqdpdgkyvxb?file=src%2Fmain.ts

Comment: Can you show code of your custom `MaterialModule` too?

Comment: I think the problem is involved with how you're importing `from "@angular/material"` in `MaterialModule`. You should instead import each individual module as needed in `MaterialModule` including your `MatBottomSheetModule`. I have updated my answer for your reference.

Comment: I'd recommend building a stackblitz to replicate the source code environment you have as this problem seems deeper than it looks like on the surface.

Comment: Hi!!, 
I tried to create the environment but I could not achieve it, but I uploaded my project to this repository https://github.com/kiozzer/ionic-zk1s9e.git

Comment: Awesome will take a look today

Comment: great ! thank you very much, even so I will continue looking for more possible solutions

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have following things.

1). in your login-page.module.ts file, "BottomSheetOverviewExampleSheet" in declarations and entryComponents
like this,

```
import { LoginPageRoutingModule } from './login-routing.module';
import { LoginPage, BottomSheetOverviewExampleSheet } from './login.page';
import { MaterialModule } from '../material.module';
import { MatBottomSheetModule } from '@angular/material/bottom-sheet';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    LoginPageRoutingModule,
    MaterialModule,
    MatBottomSheetModule

  ],
  declarations: [LoginPage, BottomSheetOverviewExampleSheet],
  entryComponents: [BottomSheetOverviewExampleSheet],
})
export class LoginPageModule {}
```

2). hope you have bottom-sheet-overview-example-sheet.html
like this,

```
<mat-nav-list>
  <a mat-list-item (click)="openLink($event)">
    <span mat-line>
      <!--Your message To Show -->
       Test Message
    </span>
  </a>
</mat-nav-list>
```